# Synchronizing email files from old to new exim causes problems in pop3 client

Tags: outlook, pop3, exim

We moved from the old server to the new server and synchronized email files bilaterally between the two servers
There was no problem for IMAP clients, but POP3 clients (in Outlook) did not receive the emails that were sent during the transfer time (change of DNS).

How does Outlook detect when new emails are received?
What solution do you suggest for this problem?

Creating a new profile solves the problem, but the number of clients is large and not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave messages on the server, Outlook keeps track of the message ids it processed. The ids are stored in a hidden (associated) message with `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.MessageManager"`. You can see that message in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - go to the Inbox folder in Outlook, click IMAPIFolder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the "Associated Contents" tab. Locate me4sages (you can have more than one) with `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.MessageManager"`, double click to open. Go to the GetAttachmentTable tab and double click to open the attachment. Select `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN`property, click "..." button next to the Value edit box to see the attachment contents.